# installshield- cannot delete registry key during uninstall

Tags: batch-file, installshield, windows-installer, regedit

I have installer with chained msi.

If i do uninstall, it doesn't remove the registry key of the chaind msi.
i tried to solve it with many ways but i didn't succeed.

I'm writing my ways hoping someone will find where it went wrong:

1. I wrote a batch file:

   REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{product code} /f

This batch file remove the registry key when i run it stand alone, but if i put it via the installshield as a custom action it failed.

2. By custom action:

   LaunchAppAndWait("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ", "/C REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{product code} /f", WAIT);
3. By custom action that tun the batch file

   LaunchAppAndWait("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ", "/C \"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\remove registryKey.bat\"", WAIT);
4. MsiExec.exe  /x{GUID} - failed because it cannot run two installation in parallel

I really need your help!!!
I have been trying to solve it a long time ago without success.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 or 64 bit machine? Chances are you are running a 32 bit install on a 64 bit machine. It is probably deleting the wrong registry key (32/64 bit). See the help by doing REG DELETE /?

Notice the /reg:32 and /reg:64 parameters. Use the appropriate one.

Also check for error in bat file. Pause on error (at least until you get the code correct).